# PXE Boot error in virtualBox

Tags: pxe-boot

I've installed WDS on my windows server 2012 correctly and everything is fine, but when I setup a new machine to boot from PXE, it get the error below.

Note, The server have been installed on VirtualBox too.

[image]

The new machine network configuration is shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your VB client is really booting iPXE; set it to boot real "PXE" instead.

Comment: Oh yea; mine is a perfectly valid answer. The client is booting into a mode that is not compatible with MS boot managers. Of course my answer requires a minimum PXE background.

Comment: Ok, +1. But: maybe it would look much better if you gave more details. I've found your answer in the VLQ queue.